# Determining whether $2x ^ 3 - x^2 + 1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm checking if $f(x) = 2x ^ 3 - x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

We have a polynomial of degree three so if it has no roots it is irreducible. But as we are dealing with $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ it is not easy to check the roots, apart from the trivial options such as $0, 1$.

Eisenstein criterion's can't be applied. I tried subbing in some values such as $(x + 1)$ but found that Eisenstein still was not applicable.

So what other options do I have?

Comment: Are you familiar with the rational roots theorem? This specifies the form that any roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ must take.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that theorem. So in this case the possible roots are $\{\pm\frac{1}{2}\}$ and neither of them are roots?...Yet wolfram alpha says this polynomial does have a root...?

Comment: The root that Wolfram gives is not rational, so the polynomial has no roots over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Don't use computer algebra systems before you understand the mathematics behind it.

Comment: @T.Bongers It gives a real root that appears to be rational, althought maybe it is just rounding off digits past a certain point?

Comment: @sonicboom If you click "exact form," you'll see it's not rational. Regardless, the rational roots theorem implies that the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1$ and $\pm 1/2$, so there's no worries.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = 2x^3 - x^2 + 1$.  Note that, since $\deg(f) \leq 3$, it is irreducible over the rationals $\iff$ $f$ has no rational roots.  From here, we can apply the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  This tells us that the set of possible roots is $\displaystyle \left\{ \pm 1, \ \pm \frac{1}{2} \right\}$, and one can check that these all fail to satisfy $f(\alpha) = 0$.  Therefore, it will not split into a product of two smaller-degree polynomials *with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$*.

---

**Alternative method**: It is a theorem that if a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible modulo a prime $p$, then it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Notice that $f$ reduces as $f(x) = 2x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 \pmod{3}$.  As above, it suffices to show that $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, which is easier given that we only have $3$ things to check.  Evaluated modulo $3$, we have $f(0) \equiv 1$, $ \ \ f(1) \equiv 2$, and $f(2) \equiv 1$.  We see that $f$ has no roots modulo $3$, so it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, and thus it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.